# How to retrieve the last N entries from guild.audit_logs

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that retrieves the last hundred audit logs but I've hit a few problems

This is my current code for my audit logs command

```
@client.command()
async def serverlogs(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    entries = guild.audit_logs(limit=100)
    await ctx.send(f'Audit Log:  {entries}')
```

but the only output I get is this

```
Audit Log:  <discord.iterators.AuditLogIterator object at 0x000002402BE84DF0>
```

and I'm not really sure what it means. Can someone explain to me in detail what is going on with my code and what I'm doing wrong? I'm genuinely interested in learning more about discord.py.

Comment: your `entries` variable is an `iterator`. It is very similar to a array or `list`. You need to iterate over it. Furthermore `guild_audit_logs` is a coroutine. You need to put an `await` in front of it or you do `async for entry in guild.audit_logs` see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=audit_logs#discord.Guild.audit_logs

Answer (score 1):

You get an iterator (`<discord.iterators.AuditLogIterator>`).

You need to iterate it.

```
entries = await guild.audit_logs(limit=100)
for entry in entries:
    # ... do something with the entry, e.g. collect it into a string, print it, send it
```